# Docker Build access denied

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, streamlit

I've been trying to get past this error in VS code when building in docker on an M1 Macbook. I attached my dockerfile and error message. Not sure if the M1 is causing some issues or not. I was able to change the docker engine settings and change it the features buildkit to "false" since it was true before and that helped me get moving along. I logged in and out of using `docker login` & `docker logout` and when I do the build again, I still get the same error message that the pull access denied.

dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9-slim

# Setup env
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER 1

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM base AS python-deps

# Install pipenv and compilation dependencies
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc lsb-release

# Install python dependencies in /.venv
COPY Pipfile .
COPY Pipfile.lock .
RUN PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 pipenv install --deploy

# Record information about Linux distribution
RUN lsb_release -ds > /.lsb-release


#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM base AS runtime

ARG GIT_COMMIT_SHA GIT_COMMIT_SHA_SHORT GIT_COMMIT_MSG GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_NAME GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_DATE_ISO8601 GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_DATE_UNIX GIT_URL GIT_WEB_URL
RUN echo "GIT_COMMIT_SHA=${GIT_COMMIT_SHA}"
RUN echo "GIT_COMMIT_SHA_SHORT=${GIT_COMMIT_SHA_SHORT}"
RUN echo "GIT_COMMIT_MSG=${GIT_COMMIT_MSG}"
RUN echo "GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=${GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL}"
RUN echo "GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_NAME=${GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_NAME}"
RUN echo "GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_DATE_ISO8601=${GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_DATE_ISO8601}"
RUN echo "GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_DATE_UNIX=${GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_DATE_UNIX}"
RUN echo "GIT_URL=${GIT_URL}"
RUN echo "GIT_WEB_URL=${GIT_WEB_URL}"
ENV GIT_COMMIT_SHA=${GIT_COMMIT_SHA} \
    GIT_COMMIT_SHA_SHORT=${GIT_COMMIT_SHA_SHORT} \
    GIT_COMMIT_MSG=${GIT_COMMIT_MSG} \
    GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=${GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL} \
    GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_NAME=${GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_NAME} \
    GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_DATE_ISO8601=${GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_DATE_ISO8601} \
    GIT_URL=${GIT_URL} \
    GIT_WEB_URL=${GIT_WEB_URL} \
    GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_DATE_UNIX=${GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_DATE_UNIX}

# Copy virtual env from python-deps stage
COPY --from=python-deps /.venv /.venv
COPY --from=python-deps /.lsb-release /.lsb-release
ENV PATH="/.venv/bin:$PATH"

# Create and switch to a new user
RUN useradd --create-home appuser
WORKDIR /home/appuser
USER appuser

# Install application into container
COPY . .

RUN streamlit --version | cut -d' ' -f3 > streamlit-version
```

now here is my error code:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  34.45MB
Step 1/33 : FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9-slim
 ---> ae64b82339a8
Step 2/33 : ENV LANG C.UTF-8
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5f0920efde24
Step 3/33 : ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2eb01b896c74
Step 4/33 : ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ce8e702d0b31
Step 5/33 : ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 167c8aaab6ce
Step 6/33 : FROM base AS python-deps
pull access denied for base, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Comment: Why can't you post that as code? It's just text, and including the text in your question would make it much easier for people who would like to help out.

Comment: Do not post the error message as an image, post it as *text* in the question itself

Comment: In any case, what do you expect `base` to be here, exactly? Did you mean to name the first part `base`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker doesn't know what `base` is. You need to define it. In the code below, I assume you want `base` to be `python:3.9-slim`. The subsequent `FROM` steps will use the image made by the first `FROM` section.

```
FROM python:3.9-slim AS base
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER 1

FROM base AS python-deps
RUN pip install pipenv
# ...

FROM base AS runtime
# ...
```